# Unable to parse custom log file format using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find and plot the hourly error rate in a custom log file that looks like this.

```
<2019-12-19T16:02:14.776+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>
 --ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: DeploymentMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:02:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: WKWLUTVWBDJ2GAGOIRZL5VHMK3ZTJIWX>
<2019-12-19T16:04:12.242+0000> WARNING <ACTION.JCB> <e646de45-4c09-4a6e-a5d1-3552db8fc0dc-0000000b> Failed to get business interface of sdpinternal.messaging.management.em.ServerTargetImpl, class will not be monitored.  <Ref: N2IOE3DZNWKAYSYLJTN5AWRQJP7DKMTS>
<2019-12-19T16:04:14.745+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>
 --ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: HostMetric[1] DeploymentMetric[1] JVMMetric[1] InfrastructureMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1] ThreadPoolMetric[1] AppServerMetric[1] ConnectionPoolMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://omc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.omc.ocp.oraclecloud.com/static/data.storage/apm_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:04:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: PU5HERXNVLSVAG33LIOPJVKYSZJC4R73>
<2019-12-19T16:04:14.753+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.transport> Error connecting to https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric  <Ref: NL6XDJAALZ23BM4PPRRFWRFFBC6KLYSE>
```

I would like to plot the number of "500 Internal Server Error" in every hour. I tried to parse this log into a pandas dataframe using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO


tmp=u"""<2019-12-19T16:02:14.776+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>
 --ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: DeploymentMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:02:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: WKWLUTVWBDJ2GAGOIRZL5VHMK3ZTJIWX>
<2019-12-19T16:04:12.242+0000> WARNING <ACTION.JCB> <e646de45-4c09-4a6e-a5d1-3552db8fc0dc-0000000b> Failed to get business interface of sdpinternal.messaging.management.em.ServerTargetImpl, class will not be monitored.  <Ref: N2IOE3DZNWKAYSYLJTN5AWRQJP7DKMTS>
<2019-12-19T16:04:14.745+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>
 --ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: HostMetric[1] DeploymentMetric[1] JVMMetric[1] InfrastructureMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1] ThreadPoolMetric[1] AppServerMetric[1] ConnectionPoolMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://omc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.omc.ocp.oraclecloud.com/static/data.storage/apm_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:04:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: PU5HERXNVLSVAG33LIOPJVKYSZJC4R73>
<2019-12-19T16:04:14.753+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.transport> Error connecting to https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric  <Ref: NL6XDJAALZ23BM4PPRRFWRFFBC6KLYSE>"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(tmp), comment=' --', sep='0> ', names=['Time','Text'])
indexNames = df[ (df['Time'].str.startswith(' --')) ].index
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

# remove < by strip and convert column Time to_datetime:
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time.str.strip('<'), format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+0000')
df.Text = df.Text.str.strip()

print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

For some reason I am unable to remove rows from the dataframe.

I am using pandas 0.24.2 with Python 3.7.3 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The affected rows does not start with any spaces. Replace `startswith(' --')` with `startswith('--')`:

```
indexNames = df[ (df['Time'].str.startswith('--')) ].index
```

---

On a side note, your `comment=' --'` parameter in `pd.read_csv()` doesn't work. According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html),

> **comment** : str, optional
>
> Indicates remainder of line should not be parsed. If found at the beginning of a line, the line will be ignored altogether. **This parameter must be a single character.**

Comment: You are correct. And thanks for the comment on comment :-) Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find and plot the hourly error rate in a custom log
>   file that looks like this.

Log files naturally contain the end of the line information. So if you have access to the log file, I recommend directly processing over the log file.

```
errors = []
with open("log.txt", "r") as log:
    for line in log:
        if "500 Internal Server Error" in line:
            errors.append(datetime.strptime(line.strip().split()[0], '<%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+0000>'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': errors})
```

Testing

```
log = [
"""<2019-12-19T16:02:14.776+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>""",
"""--ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: DeploymentMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:02:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: WKWLUTVWBDJ2GAGOIRZL5VHMK3ZTJIWX>""",
"""<2019-12-19T16:04:12.242+0000> WARNING <ACTION.JCB> <e646de45-4c09-4a6e-a5d1-3552db8fc0dc-0000000b> Failed to get business interface of sdpinternal.messaging.management.em.ServerTargetImpl, class will not be monitored.  <Ref: N2IOE3DZNWKAYSYLJTN5AWRQJP7DKMTS>""",
"""<2019-12-19T16:04:14.745+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.smaap> Response NOT OK --Transport content: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body bgcolor="white"><center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center><hr><center> </center></body></html>""",
"""--ServiceInfo: PostDataService - client: A201ACCDC3DAB47C0B4BF021D11785DFD49F1863 ,tenant: 19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88 ,payloadType: apm_metric ,messageForClient: false Observations: HostMetric[1] DeploymentMetric[1] JVMMetric[1] InfrastructureMetric[1] MappingMetric[1] RequestTypeMetric[1] LinkMetric[1] ThreadPoolMetric[1] AppServerMetric[1] ConnectionPoolMetric[1]  --Transport info: HTTP method: POST ,URL: https://omc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.omc.ocp.oraclecloud.com/static/data.storage/apm_metric ,response status: 500 ,response headers: Connection=keep-alive , Content-Length=182 , Date=Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:04:14 GMT , Content-Type=text/html   <Ref: PU5HERXNVLSVAG33LIOPJVKYSZJC4R73>""",
"""<2019-12-19T16:04:14.753+0000> WARNING <clientToServer.transport> Error connecting to https://oc-19b0be25fd5248588f0631a820a43c88.api.smouloud.com/static/data.storage/m_metric  <Ref: NL6XDJAALZ23BM4PPRRFWRFFBC6KLYSE>"""
]

errors = []

#with open("log.txt", "r") as log:
for line in log:
    if "500 Internal Server Error" in line:
        errors.append(datetime.strptime(line.strip().split()[0], '<%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f+0000>'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': errors})
```

Comment: Nice. That's a super, easy way.